# A strange pixel offset when zooming overlayed images in html and css

Tags: css, image, zooming, overlay, html-rendering

The problem appears when zooming two overlayed images (even of the same size).

In my scenario, I had two transparent images `<img>` of the same size (width x height): a background image and a cropped header. I overlayed them with an absolute position in a relative `<div>` container of a known width. I tried to zoom in and out using the normal browser zoom functionality, and I noticed pixel offset between the two layers on different zoom factors! However, 100% was a perfect fit.

Technically, I tried to have one `<div>` tag with two `background-image` URLs (using CSS) of the same images. I also tried to have an SVG that holds both PNG images. And I have tried to use images of different sizes (always same width, different height).

**NONE** of my experiments worked. There was always an offset on different zooms.

I would like to know if someone has an explanation for such a behavior or am I just missing something here?

---

Eventually, the preferred solution was to draw both images on a canvas and apply the zooming on it.

I have created the following JSFiddle to demonstrate my problem:
 Initially, the width is 100%, try zooming in and out using the buttons and observe the offset.

```js
function zoomIn() {
  var width = 0;
  $('img').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width() * 1.1);
    width = $(this).width() / 1918 * 100;
  });
  $('#size').text(Number.parseFloat(width).toPrecision(4) + "%");
}

function zoomOut() {
  var width = 0;
  $('img').each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width() / 1.1);
    width = $(this).width() / 1918 * 100;
  });
  $('#size').text(Number.parseFloat(width).toPrecision(4) + "%");
}

document.getElementById("zoomIn").addEventListener("click", zoomIn);
document.getElementById("zoomOut").addEventListener("click", zoomOut);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1918px;
}

#size {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://imgur.com/N1BK4Kk.png">
  <img src="https://imgur.com/LFG04gn.png">
</div>

<div id="size">

</div>

<footer>
  <button id="zoomIn">zoom in</button>
  <button id="zoomOut">zoom out</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: I just changed the background to red and that little grey line turned red => it's the background shining through. Maybe just set it to white as a workaround?

Comment: couldn't do that since my images can be of any color, it's not a fixed web page that I'm using...

Answer (score 1):

The bottom image has a transparent rectangle top area. There is no gradient - it is a sharp transition from transparent to white. This statement is only valid for 100% zoom. Once you start zooming, anti-aliasing will be in effect. Only the image's boundaries will be placed pixel-perfect by the browser. But the anti-aliasing within the image cannot be pixel-accurate when it comes to the question "at which Y coordinate turns the white area into transparent". And if that transparent area is just a little bit higher than expected, it will extend under the other image. Maybe just a fraction of one pixel line. But then the grey background will shine through. That's because anti-aliasing between opaque white and transparent will be half-transparent grey. Depending on the zoom, you will get sometimes "overlapping" and sometimes "underlapping", because the boundaries of the top images will still be rendered pixel-perfect.
Your assumption is to exactly cover up the transparent area of the second image with the top image. That would usually work with CSS, but not if you only want to cover up a fraction of the second image pixel-perfect. So it kind of makes sense. Get rid of the transparent area to resolve this?
If the general style of this webpage is white, maybe just change the body's background color to white for a quick solution?

Comment: This is really good!
This did not solve the problem but it helps to understand the issue with the antialiasing of sharp transitions from opaque to transparent.
I say it is not fixable with css without loss of quality.
Only solveable if you have access to the source image and crop less pixels out to have a color if the background image shines through.

Comment: just to understand, you're saying that the problem is with the antialiasing that is done by the browser renderer on zooming of the transparent edges of the images?

Comment: Yes - you are trying to align some other image to this edge within the image. But the edge will get blurred if you zoom in. Probably also if you show the page on a high resolution screen when all the images are scaled up. Generally speaking, you can align the boundaries of images, but not the content, because rendering the pixels is the responsibility of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's just rendering problem. Probably browser related as it can't fit pixels with good enough precision when zoom is different than 100%. The best I could come up with is `image-rendering` but it lowers image quality

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    image-rendering: optimizespeed;
}
```

I could also suggest getting rid of this sharp cut form header bottom part. It's supposed to be shadow anyway so make it transparent shadow.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Even if you change the width CSS property for the images for zooming, you will still notice the pixel offset. I only added the buttons for nicer usability.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a resource for that information or is it an assumption? then maybe I could find a clue for another solution that wouldn't affect the quality of the image.

Comment: Just an assumption.

Comment: @Mick you don't need these buttons (It is just for nicer usability like HanaTam said). You can also use the Browser zoom for this which is not a fraction